# LAS files not identified in lidR

Tags: las, lidr, files

When I try to upload the las file to work on lidR package it give the following error.
The code I used to upload the file
las <-readLAS("<Sample.las>")

> Error in streamLAS.character(files, ofile = "", select, filter) :
> File(s) are not las or laz

Comment: Are you sure it is really a LAS file ? I mean a laser point cloud file. It already happened that some folk were trying to open [log ASCII standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_ASCII_standard) file.